# complete list of wowza ModuleBase events?

Tags: application-development

does anybody knows where I can find full list of events supported by Wowza ModuleBase class !?

ex. onSessionCreate, onRTPSessionCreate, onAppStart, etc..

edit: I just realised that this question should stay in stackoverflow, rather than askubuntu, but I'll not deleted in case someone need this answer, just like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted same question on wowza forum the answer I have received is:

> Please refer to the [install-dir]/documentation/WowzaStreamingEngine_ServerSideAPI.pdf

this somehow answered my question, so after a research in documentation I have found all needed information, but I had to dig in all pdf documents and html help present in that folder

http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?38670-all-events-supported-by-ModuleBase&p=143807#post143807